# What does the Google Java SDK version nomenclature mean?

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

When using different Google Java SDKs, you include the right version which is defined by, for instance, **v2-rev292-1.21.0** for the latest BigQuery library version. I suppose the syntax is something like this : *version-revision-some other version*, but I can't seem to be able to find an explanation for the relationship between the three parts. This is problematic when you need to upgrade versions and finding out that updates give compilation errors without changing (what I thought) was a minor version.

Can somebody explain precisely the Google SDK versioning nomenclature? In particular, what does the second version mean?

Comment: It looks like `v2` refers to the version of the web API. The other parts probably refer to the version of the library itself. Can you mention the versions you tried (which worked, which didn't)?

Comment: One example of a version change that is confusing; my current version of the Google Analytics library is **v3-rev112-1.19.0** and checking mvn repository, there are three different relases made in April 2016: **v3-rev129-1.19.1**, **v3-rev129-1.20.0* and **v3-rev129-1.21.1**. Which one should I use?


In addition, upgrading beyond **v3-rev112-1.19.0** while staying in the 1.19.0 track will break my current implementation, since some features have been removed between two simple revisions. Or at least according to my understanding of the versioning numenclature.

Comment: Google has explicitly marked `v3` as legacy and encourages you to upgrade to `v4` anyway.  But if upgrading from something marked `1.19.0` to `1.19.1` breaks your program, you can assume that the implementors either made a mistake, or have [underscore.js-like understandings of "minor" changes](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/1805). To be honest, I think the latter is more likely, so compatibility should only be expected with exactly one version of the library.

Comment: Well, the break occurs when changing `revXXX` while staying in the `v3` track for the `1.19.0` subversion. Keep in mind that this is only an example for Google Analytics (I could probably provide other examples too), and that I'm trying to figure out what the nomenclature actually means on a general level.